# How do I access a pointer member inside a structure in C?

Tags: c, pointers, member, member-pointers

```
struct sample
{
    int a;
    char b;
    float c;
    int *al;
    union un
    {
        int a;
        char c;
        float f;
    }*ptr;
}test;
```

How do I access the structure member 'al' and the union members a,c,f?

Comment: sample.ptr->a work for you? Or *(sample.al)?

Comment: I would like to use 'test' and 'ptr' when accessing them al and a,c,f respec. How does that work?

Comment: `test.ptr->a;` will work.

Answer (score 4):

No difference than others:

1. access `al`

   ```
   test.al
   ```

   If you want the value of `al`, you could get it by `*(test.al)`.
2. access `a`, `c`, `f`

   ```
   test.ptr->a;
   test.ptr->c;
   test.ptr->f;
   ```

Comment: Still have to dereference test.al. test->al won't work, obviously, because you're not dereferencing test, so *(test.al) would make it clearer.

Comment: @ciphermagi `test.al` is the variable itself, `*(test.al)` is the value of that variable. Anyway, you have a point. Answer updated.

Comment: I'm not convinced that `*(test.al)` is clearer than `*test.al`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I guess that depends on how familiar with C operator precedence you are

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you need to dereference the pointer.

Normally we would do this to dereference the union.

`test.*ptr.a.`

The problem with this is that the compiler will execute the dotnotation before the dereferencing symbol, The compiler will therefore dereference the field in the union, instead of the union it self.

To solve this issue we can put ´*ptr´in parentheses to force deferencing the union before accesing the field. Like this.

`test.(*ptr).a`

For an easier syntax this can also be written as

`test.ptr->a`